# Subversion: base checksum mismatch

Tags: svn

I am trying to commit a change in subversion to a file. This file belongs to a directory that is linked to my project via an external, and is pegged at a certain revision.

When I do a commit, I get the error:

```
Commit failed
Base checksum mismatch on....
```

I tried to check out the directory again to ensure that it was clean and perform the commit again, but I still receive the same error.

Could it be related to committing to a pegged file? I thought that committing onto a file that is pegged should be possible and essentially branches off this code?

Answer (score 52):

The way worked for me:

1. Make copy of problematic file.
2. Revert.
3. Unversion and add to ignore item.
4. Commit.
5. Owerwrite ignored file from copy.
6. Add file back to SVN.
7. Commit.

Comment: Without access to the SVN repository, this was the cleanest solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: Unversion-ing was what solved it for me.  In eclipse I created a copy of the file with a different name, deleted the corrupted file, SVN-added the new file, and then renamed the new file back to original file name. Thanks

Comment: I tried this solution and while it works, it also removes the svn-history of that file, so you should carefully evaluate if that's something you can live with.

Comment: The REAL solution. Thanks

Comment: For me, the primary value of SVN is having a version history. This method creates a break in that version history, and disrupts SVN's ability to properly restore sets of programs that may depend on each other. So I prefer the solution from @mike nelson.

Answer (score 11):

Copy all files in your project to a temporary backup folder. Click "Revert" on your original project folder. Diff changed files with the backup folder, copy your changed files into the original project folder. Commit and your original folder is back to normal.

Just had this same issue on two projects and that method worked.

Comment: Revert didn't work for me, but moving the entire directory then updating (which restored the directory) then moving the modified files back into the dir did the trick for me.

Comment: Revert didn't work for me either, but deleting the entire directory, then updating, then moving the modified files back (but not of course the .svn directory) did the trick for me too.

Answer (score 6):

The way that worked best for me, was:

1. Doing an Export of the whole folder that won't commit (using Tortoise for example)
2. Delete the folder currently in SVN (also using your SVN client)
3. Put the folder you exported everything to, at the same place as the previously deleted folder, preferably with the same name
4. Add and Commit the folder
5. You are back where you were without losing your changes and without wrong checksums!

Answer (score 4):

I did this.

1. Deleted the .svn folder in the workspace.
2. Checked out the project to a new temporary folder
3. Copied the .svn folder from the new temporary folder
4. Pasted the .svn folder into the workspace.
5. Committed without issue.
6. Delete temporary folder.

Comment: Quick and easy, and does not change the repository at all (except in the final commit, which is what I was trying to do in the first place). Thanks.

Comment: +1, this fixed it for me. But be aware to download all the incoming changes before doing it, otherwise it will mess you up

Comment: Best solution, because preserve file history, unlike some other solutions

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue and I used console client to deal with it:

1. Backup files
2. Delete files from repo by `svn rm filename`
3. Commit it
4. Copy files back from backup use `svn add filename`
5. Commit it

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, but deleting the folders didn't seem to do anything.

I managed to fix this by checkouting the same source files to another place and copying over the files which had these problems.

Clean / Revert / Update(after deleting the files) did nothing.

I'm running windows 7 with tortoisesvn 1.7.11 64 bit version.

Comment: This worked for me as well, using command line `svn` in linux.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue and I used console client to deal with it:

1. Backup files
2. Delete files from repo by svn rm filename
3. Commit it
4. Copy files back from backup use svn add filename
5. Commit it

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is to:

```
svn up --set-depth=empty
```

then

```
svn up --set-depth=infinity
```

error is gone!

Comment: To be complete, assume problem file is foo.cpp.
Run:  
`cp filename filename.save`   
`svn up --set-depth=empty filename  `   
`svn up --set-depth=infinity filename  `   
`meld filename filename.save`

Comment: Not a good solution.
I ran both commands and my files have been gone. :-(

Comment: This did not work for me, and will at least temporarily remove EVERY FILE.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way IMHO is:
1. Checkout the last copy from your repository into some directory (f.e. TTTT).
2. Copy TTTT/.svn content to your normal source directory (override the existing content).
You are done - the original directory may be committed.

Answer (score 1):

For me, a new checkout would be very time consuming (several gigs thousands of files).
What I did:

- delete the file with corrupted metadata (keep local file, or back it up)
- it did not complain about metadata mismatch
- commit
- add file back to working copy
- commit !
- profit!

Answer (score 0):

Your working copy maybe corrupted. You may try to repair it with SmartSVN (select Modify | Validate Admin Area). If this won't help only a fresh checkout will help.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

1. Make copy of current version of file.
2. svn rm 'filename'
3. svn ci
4. change the file name back to the original
5. svn add 'filename'
6. svn ci

After this, the commits and updates seem to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Check your server's SVN version it might be mismatch with your local svn** version. 
1. Check SVN version by following command and upgrade it, if its mismatch with your server version.

```
svn --version
```

2. Checkout the project with latest version of SVN (i.e. your server svn version).
3. Commit the file.

Note : It will work only for SVN version mismatch case.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue as the following
First, backup the folder where the problem is
2ns, Delete the original folder and commit it.
3rd, copy folder from backup folder
4th, I could commit this folder without the issue

This may not be the good solution, since, I delete the folder and commit, So that I think I can not revert it after I fixed this issue if I want to.

Answer (score 0):

I simply removed the file from the working directory, then did svn up. Example:

```
rm dir/bad-file.txt
svn up dir/bad-file.txt
```

That worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me also this one worked:

- Delete entire local folder
- checkout the repository